# Passing parameters in the Form constructor, winforms c#

Tags: winforms, constructor, asp.net-3.5

I have a following inheritance hierarchy:

Class A : Form 
Class B : Class A

Class A needs to be able to accept a parameter so that I can create the instance of Class B like this:

```
ClassB mynewFrm = new ClassB(param);
```

How do I define such a constructor in Class A?

thanks!

I am using Winforms in .net 3.5, c#

EDITED:
Class A and Class B are defined as forms, using partial classes. 
So I guess this is turning into a question about partial classes and custom (overriden) constructors.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete demo sample that demostrates required behaviour.

For the sake of ease your learning, I chose a **string** type parameter that you adjust to your case.

To test it, create a new **Visual Studio** **C#** project and fill **program.cs** with the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stackoverflow
{

    public class ClassA : Form
    {
        public ClassA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ClassA(string WindowTitleParameter)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = WindowTitleParameter;
            MessageBox.Show("Hi! I am ClassB constructor and I have 1 argument. Clic OK and look at next windows title");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent() // Usually, this method is located on ClassA.Designer.cs partial class definition
        {
            // ClassA initialization code goes here
        }

    }

    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        // The following defition will prevent ClassA's construtor with no arguments from being runned
        public ClassB(string WindowTitleParameter) : base(WindowTitleParameter) 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.Text = WindowTitleParameter;
            //MessageBox.Show("Hi! I am ClassB constructor and I have 1 argument. Clic OK and look at next windows title");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent() // Usually, this method is located on ClassA.Designer.cs partial class definition
        {
            // ClassB initialization code goes here
        }

    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// The main entry point for the application. 
        /// </summary> 
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            // If you debug this code using StepInto, you will notice that contructor of ClassA (argumentless)
            // will run prior to contructor of classB (1 argument)

            Application.Run(new ClassB("Look at me!"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class A needs to be able to accept the parameter, not class B. Don't I need to call InitializeComponent() routine in the constructor at some point?

Comment: when I implement the constructor above, it complains that "'ClassA' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments"

Comment: Hi sarname. I just done a code revision that will allow you to use the same parameter either on ClassA or ClassB. I would suggest you to use debugger's STEP-INTO feature to get a better insight on code flow. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A constructor for class would look like this.

```
private Object _object1;

public ClassA(object object1)
{
    _object1 = object1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `ClassA` your constructor would look like

```
public ClassA(Object param)
{
    //...
}
```

and for `ClassB` it would look like

```
public ClassB(Object param) : base(param) 
{
    //...
}
```

where `base(param)` will actually be calling the `ClassA` constructor that accepts that parameter.