# can i add parenthesis to overridden method?

Tags: c#, overriding, parentheses

when am passing values through overridden function am getting an error at compile time

air_ticket_reservation_testing.employee_price.getprice(bool)': no suitable method found to override

```
class price
{
    int iprice;
    public virtual int getprice()
    {
        iprice = 1000;
        return iprice;
    }
}
class pprice : price
{
    int iprice = 500;
    public override int getprice(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

.

and what does this mean "return base.getprice();" it comes auto

```
class pprice : price
{
    int iprice = 500;
    public override int getprice(int i)
    {
        return base.getprice();
    }
}
```

Comment: `int getprice()` is not the same signature as `int getprice(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can override methods/functions that are markerd with the `virtual` keyword. You're also able to override methods/functions with the `new` keyword ( this is not adviced because of the unmaintainable and unpredictable calls ). This also requires to be a method/function with the same signature, otherwise it would be an `overload`. In you're case should the override look like this :

```
class pprice : price
{
    int iprice = 500;
    public override int getprice()
    {
        // do other stuff

        return base.getprice();
    }
}
```

the `base` keyword inside classes revers to the 'base' class. With this keyword you're able to call the `protected`/`public` `properties`/`fields`/`methods`/`functions` from the price class. The example code above calls the `base.getprice()` method. this refers to the getprice() method from the price class.

Comment: got it
btw i ve got another problem and stackoverflow has disabled me for asking anymore questions if its possible can you tell me that can i change label name from the forms constructor which has a string passing through while its instance

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753947/passing-parameters-in-the-form-constructor-winforms-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can only override a method if the entire signature matches exactly. Otherwise you can overload it (which creates a method with the same name but different parameters).

And `return base.getprice()` simply calls the method that you're overriding in case you need to use that code as well (rather than re-implement the old behavior in your new method as well).